# How to install the full Qt 5.5 to default location

Tags: qt, qt-creator

https://github.com/mavlink/qgroundcontrol
Follow the installation guide from the readme file in qgroundcontrol, I still have problem of missing package in QT. I have downloaded QT installer (https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/) and installed it to "home/user/QT".

It this problem because...
I installed to the wrong location which is not default location of QT then QT cannot find new installed-packages. Where is the default location to install?
or I have to do some more configuration?

OS : Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Ubuntu 16.04 there is Qt 5.5.1 in the standard OS repositories.

```
sudo apt install qtbase5-dev libqt5location5 qtdeclarative5-controls-plugin
```